# how to change the output encoding, while displaying a file through php

Tags: php, encoding

how to change the output encoding, while displaying a file through php

Comment: You mean actually changing the encoding *while* you deliver data? That can't be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `header('Content-type: text/foo; charset=bar');` to set the appropriate encoding, and use [`iconv`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php) to change the actual encoding of the file you are displaying if it does not match.